# Can we integrate the QGIS map in the web applications?

Tags: google-maps, qgis

I have a web application where I want to show the car patrolling on the Geo map. Is it possible to integrate QGIS map for web application.

Comment: post what you have tried with question

Comment: I have my own qgis map. I need to show that qgis map into my web application instead of google maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the QGIS map in kml and then load the kml maps in google maps I think this is the simplest way.

For QGIS you can export your layer in KML with right click on the layer, then save as  format Keyhole markup language.

For import KML in google maps  you can see this google developer sample

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Comment: Can you give me a example or tutorial web link.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. The simplest is to use the plugin **qgis2leaf**. There are many howtos and videos about it, one of them is [Leaflet Web Maps with qgis](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html)

EDIT: In answer to a comment, to install qgis2leaf, as [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html):

1. Go to menu **Plugins ‣ Manage and Install Plugin**
2. Search for "qgis2leaf" (if it is not on list, try to enable **Show also experimental plugins** on the Settings tab)
3. Select "qgis2leaf" and then... **INSTALL**!

Comment: I have qgis Desktop 2.8 version, can you let me know how to plug in qgis2leaf. I am on Linux platform.

Comment: I am on the Linux platform, when I going plugins-> Settings It has shown "No python supported detected, thus no settings available".

Comment: which Linux distribution do you have? Have you compiled QGIS or installed a deb/rpm package?

Comment: Distribution : Ubuntu 14.04, installed from terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   I resolved this problem by installing python and set the PYTHONPATH. Command for installing python on ubuntu : sudo apt-get install python-qgis-common